# Frame 2:26 - Why does conso have a strange cube?

Tags: scheme, reasoned-schemer

In frame 26 we get the definition for cons<sup>0</sup>:

```lisp
(degree (conso a d p)
  (== `(,a ■ ,d) p))
```

The book hasn't mentioned yet what these black cubes are supposed to do. What does it mean?

One hint is in frame 3-4 where it is mentioned that `'(d a t e ■ s)` is not a proper list.

Comment: it says ``(defrel (consO a d p) (== `(,a . ,d) p))``, why have you written `degree`?

Comment: it is also used in 2-34 ... 2-36, on the left; 2-40, on the right, where it says `(pear . ())` is a pair, using the same little black square as a dot.

Comment: I suspect that you have a digital edition with broken typography.

Comment: @molbdnilo another possibility is that the OP typed the question by hand, selecting the unicode char manually. that would explain the "degree" in place of "defrel" too, due to the auto-correct maybe.

Comment: @WillNess Your brain is much betterer than mine.

Comment: @molbdnilo at epistemological dread, maybe. :)

Comment: In my book the cons has a superscript 0. Not sure why either.

Comment: That's a book, or a PDF of the book?

Comment: So is it "degree" in your book, or "defrel"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a dot:

```
(defrel (cons° a d p) (== `(,a . ,d) p))
```

The obsession with the quasiquote is quite unhelpful here, in my opinion. It seem much easier to me to read when written as the equivalent

```
(defrel (cons° a d p) (== (cons a d) p))
```

Comment: I considered it was a dot but what does a dot mean?

Comment: Ah, that's a Scheme question. :) it is exactly that which you see here: `(cons 1 2)` prints as `(1 . 2)`, and it also works with the backquote/quasiquote. There should be lots of Q&As about "Scheme dot list" here on SO.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bscheme%5d%20dot%20list.